# Can't get socket.io to work on server, while running fine locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

This code is running fine with the node.js server running locally:

Server:

```
var client = require('socket.io').listen(3001).sockets;
```

Client HTML:

```
<script src="http://localhost:3001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Client Javascript:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001');
```

Then I moved the server.js to my ubuntu server which has node and socket io installed, using the same code, and started it without error.

Clientside I changed the local html/javascript file from localhost:3001 to ServerIP:3001 and it just doesn't work anymore. When I check firebug, I can see it never finishes trying to GET http://ServerIP:3001/socket.io/socket.io.js. It does not fail, just never finishes.

What did I do wrong? Thank you.

Comment: What do you get if you open your browser to http://serverip:3001 ? Might be a firewall issue

Comment: Try checking is the port is blocked on the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a firewall issue.
Allow connections on port 3001 using the following (if you use iptables)

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 3001 -J ACCEPT
```

Than try again

Comment: Glad I could help!